# How to kill a task using pure python (no system commands)?

Tags: python, kill-process

I am currently trying to create a program that can kill specific tasks. I want this program to be cross-platform, so therefore, I would like to kill the tasks needed using no system commands.

Here is what I have so far...

```
import subprocess
import time
import os

def task_kill(times, task, sleep_time):
        for x in range(times):
                try:
                        subprocess.call("taskkill /IM {} /F".format(task), shell=True)
                        print("[+]Command Exected Successfully[+]")
                        time.sleep(sleep_time)
                except Exception:
                        pass

def main():
        while True:
                print(os.system("tasklist"))
                task_to_kill = str(input("Task to kill: "))
                times_to_kill = int(input("Enter times to kill task: "))
                pause = float(input("Pause time between command: "))
                task_kill(times_to_kill, task_to_kill, pause)

main()
```

[I know that task manager exists]

-Thanks again, Matt

Comment: I don't see any reasonable way to do that in a cross-platform way, especially without using anything outside of Python.

Comment: One thing you can do if you want it to be cross-platform is to make system calls, but do an operating system check to do the appropriate one depending on if the user is running Windows or Linux or w/e

Comment: Try https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil .